# What's the best way to multiply each column of a matrix to a vector in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a scaling factor such like:

```
sf<-c(0.9, 0.8, 1.1)
```

and a matrix:

```
m0<-matrix(c(1:6), nrow=2, ncol=3)     
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
```

What's the best way to multiply each column of `m` with the corresponding element of `sf` such like

```
m1<-matrix(c(0.9, 1.8, 2.4, 3.2, 5.5, 6.6), 2, 3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.9  2.4  5.5
[2,]  1.8  3.2  6.6
```

Comment: Seems like a dupe to me, but I could be convinced otherwise.

Comment: These are different questions! can you take a look in details?

Comment: I'm looking at the details. Could you be more specific? The other question starts "I have a matrix mat and a vector v. I would like to multiply first column of matrix matby first element of vector v and multiply the second column of matrix mat by second element of vector v" which sounds the same as your "multiply each column of m with the corresponding element of sf" to me.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the "best way", but you could use `sweep()`.

```
sweep(m0, 2, sf, "*")
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  0.9  2.4  5.5
# [2,]  1.8  3.2  6.6
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use `col`

```
m0 * sf[col(m0)]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  0.9  2.4  5.5
# [2,]  1.8  3.2  6.6
```

Or a double transpose

```
t(t(m0) * sf)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  0.9  2.4  5.5
# [2,]  1.8  3.2  6.6
```

Comment: R never ceases to confuse me.  The benchmarks in the linked answer say that transposing twice is fastest.  Never would have thought so.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same discussion with RHertel couple of months ago, was also very surprised.